# What's wrong with this tar command?

Tags: bash, find, tar

```
find /informatica/dev/SrcFiles* -mtime +7 -and -size +1M -exec tar -rvf files.8.2.2013.tar {} \;
```

This command is running/working correctly and I'm not sure whats wrong. I want to find the files that are over 1MB and older than 7 days and then add them to a single tar file.

Comment: Run the command without the `-exec` part. Is anything printed?

Comment: How is it failing? Your question states that it is working correctly and you're not sure what's wrong. Is _anything_ wrong? What's the problem if the command is working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` seems to be just fine:

```
$ ll
total 3072
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 1048576 Jan  1  2012 afile1M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 2097152 Jan  1  2012 afile2M

$ find . -mtime +7 -and -size +1M 
./afile2M
```

Adding in the `tar` seems fine too:

```
$ find . -mtime +7 -and -size +1M -exec tar -rvf files.8.2.2013.tar {} \;
./afile2M
```

Looking at the resulting `.tar` file it seems correct:

```
$ ll
total 5124
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 1048576 Jan  1  2012 afile1M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 2097152 Jan  1  2012 afile2M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 2099200 Aug  2 13:09 files.8.2.2013.tar

$ tar tvf files.8.2.2013.tar 
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml   2097152 2012-01-01 00:00 ./afile2M
```

Are you sure there are files that match the criteria?

Comment: I tried this out too - it works fine for me.

Comment: This seems kinda hard on the system and slower in that tar is invoked for EACH and very file it finds!  I'm definitely not sure that this is a really nice solution.

Comment: @mdpc - agreed. It's not the most efficient way to do this. I was only confirming what the OP was trying and showing that it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `cpio` over `tar` .... For example:

```
 find dirx -depth -print0 | cpio --null -o --format=crc >archive.cpio
```

You can change `crc` to `tar` for OLD tar format, or to `ustar` for POSIX.1 tar format.

You can omit the `--format` specification to default to the old CPIO bin format.